# How to install Sublime Text 2 on Raspbian Wheezy?

Tags: sublimetext2, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) and am having trouble installing Sublime Text 2. I'm using Raspbian Wheezy and need help installing Sublime Text 2.

Comment: If one of the answers below worked for you, you should accept the one that did. It awards both you and the one you accept reputation, unlocking more areas of the site for you. It's also polite :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on Tao of Mac in which he details how to use QEMU to translate the i386 binary of Sublime to ARM on the fly. I can't speak to how efficient or fast it might be, but it should at least provide a starting point.

http://taoofmac.com/space/blog/2015/02/27/2210

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text only runs on x86/x64-compatible processors from Intel and AMD, running Windows, OS X, or Linux. It does not run on the ARM Cortex, which powers your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: are there any operating systems I could install other than Raspbian to get it to work? Also, I've seen many people using Sublime Text 2 on a Raspberry Pi, including one of my friends.